# Assign user to belong to a subsite in Multisite instance

Tags: multisite, migration

I am migrating from a single wordpress site to a multisite wordpress instance. I migrated my users by copying from the table wp_user and wp_usermeta into my new multisite wordpress instance. The problem now is that all the users are only shown in the root site and I want it to be in the subsite not the root site. How do I move all the users to the other site?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your prefix is **wp_**, your blog ID of your main site is **1**, and the blog ID of your sub-site is **2**.

In the **wp_usermeta** table all rows with a **meta_key** starting with **wp_** (and not any number after it) are applied to the main site. To make them apply to the subsite, they need to start with **wp_2_** instead. This will give the users roles in the site with blog ID **2**.

You may also need to take the row from the **wp_options** table of the original single site, that has an **option_name** equal to **wp_user_roles** and put it in the table **wp_2_options** of the multisite, but also change the option name to **wp_2_user_roles**. This will move the available roles to the site with blog ID **2**.